# Trim String In Automapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm, automapper, datamapper, asp.net-mvc-5.1

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DataViewModel, DataSource>()
```

My Source Here Contains String Values Coming from user interface. I want to trim all the string before i map it to my destination object. Couldn't find a solution for this. Anyone Knows how this is to be done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using the `ForMember` method, like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DataViewModel, DataSource>()
.ForMember(x => x.YourString, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.YourString.Trim()));
```

If you want to trim more than one property you can chain the `.ForMember()` method like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DataViewModel, DataSource>()
.ForMember(x => x.YourString, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.YourString.Trim()))
.ForMember(x => x.YourString1, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.YourString1.Trim()))
.ForMember(x => x.YourString2, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.YourString2.Trim()));
```

Whilst this would get the job done, I would suggest performing input sanitisation elsewhere in your application as it doesn't belong in the mapping.

Comment: I want to do trimming for all the members of the source object not for a single one. can u tell me how that is to be done?

Comment: You can refer to @Andrew Whitaker 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30987831/4928277)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `AddTransform`

```
CreateMap<DataViewModel, DataSource>()
    .AddTransform<string>(s => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? "" : s.Trim());
```