# AutoMapper to apply common/global formatter on all fields?

Tags: .net, automapper, global, formatter

I am using AutoMapper 3.2.1

I just got a requirement where the consumers of my project want me to do some simple transformations -- have all string fields trimmed of whitespace and convert null to string.empty.

How would I do this in AutoMapper in an efficient manner?

e.g.

```
public class Person()
{
   public string First {get; set;}
   public string Middle {get; set; }
   public string Last {get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set; }
}

public class PersonDto()
{
   public string First {get; set;}
   public string Second {get; set; }
   public string Last {get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set; }
}
```

And my map example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>().
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Second, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Middle));

Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDto, Person>().
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Last, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Second));
```

I tried google to find an answer, saw that some people were using:

```
Mapper.ForSourceType<string>().AddFormatter(MyCustomStringFormatter)
```

but it seems AddFormatter is obsolete?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you truly want to apply these rules to *all* strings, you can set up a mapping from `string` to `string`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string, string>()
    .ConvertUsing(str => (str ?? "").Trim());
```

This rule will be picked up when mapping from one `string` property to another.

Comment: Warning- this will change null strings to now be returned as empty. To preserve nulls use this `.ConvertUsing(str => str == null ? null : str.Trim());`

Answer (score 4):

In my case i looked around for solution where I can Trim all string props. Not for all existing Map definitions, BUT only in some of specific map definitions.
My solution:

```
 CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      // custom map settings...
     .ForMember(x => x.Phone, opt => opt.Ignore())
      //Trim all string props now...
     .AfterMap<TrimAllStringProperty>();

        private class TrimAllStringProperty : IMappingAction<object, object>
        {
            public void Process(object source, object destination)
            {
                var stringProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
                foreach (var stringProperty in stringProperties)
                {
                    string currentValue = (string)stringProperty.GetValue(destination, null);
                    if (currentValue != null)
                        stringProperty.SetValue(destination, currentValue.Trim(), null);
                }
            }
        }
```