# .NET Core: Trim all blank spaces globally using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a request for not saving any blank spaces at the beginning and the end. I mean, I should trim every string received in the application until I save it.

I saw that there's a question that *almost* fits my request, which looks this way based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30987831/2936486) question:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string, string>()
    .ConvertUsing(str => str == null ? null : str.Trim()).Trim());
```

However, since I'm using .NET Core, `AutoMapper.Mapper` static object doesn't contain a definition of `CreateMap<>`, so I guess it might be different on this newer technology.

I tried to define something like this on my `Startup.cs`, but it didn't work:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(
    cfg => cfg.CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing(str => str == null ? null : str.Trim()),
    typeof(Startup)     
));
```

I also saw something like creating custom profile class, like `StringTrimmerProfile.cs`, and then include that profile on the Startup, but it sounds pretty much the same to what I did before. That proposal was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371548/2936486).

I don't want to perform this action on every profile, I want to do it globally for every string being mapped on the application.

How can I define a global pre-mapping to be applied on every model?
Sounds easy, but I couldn't find the answer since all the info seems to be for .NET 4.5 or lower.

**EDIT 1:**
Reading the documentation, I found the concept of [ValueTransformers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Value-transformers.html), but didn't work either.

Comment: The link is 404

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, after fighting a while, I found a solution, which probably is not the only one.

I have created a `StringTrimmerProfile.cs` which implements `AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<T, D>`:

```
public class StringTrimmerProfile : ITypeConverter<string, string>
{
    public string Convert(string source, string destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source == null ? null : source.Trim();
    }
}
```

Then, on `Startup.cs`, in `ConfigureServices()`, I did the following:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(
    cfg => cfg.CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing(new StringTrimmerProfile())
);
```

By doing this, the `Convert()` method get's triggered for every model that contains a string.